# Detect 'Like' in Facebook Social Plugin

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins

I have a webpage with a [Facebook Like](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) button (social plugin).
I need to show extra information on my page when the user has liked the page.

I know there [has been](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837999/event-handling-to-detect-if-user-clicks-a-like-button-in-xfbml-page) [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10160487/detect-facebook-like-message) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360058/facebook-like-box-how-to-detect-if-user-already-liked-the-page) but the answer has been to use the `edge.create` event to react to the user clicking the like button. This works fine except when the like happened prior to loading the page.

Others have suggested using a `signed_request` but I believe this is only applicable to canvas applications,

I know I can use the API to check for the like but this requires the user to grant permissions, but I want to do this in an anonymous manner (I am not interested in knowing who the user is, I just want to know if they liked the page).

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is  exactly the difference between having a canvas app and a site that just uses the plugins. The plugin allows (you to allow) the user to like a certain URL and that's about all. In order for the site operating outside of Facebook at explicitly access that data, it'll need the correct permissions  as you have noted... the `user_likes` permission.

Without a `signed_request` or the relevant permissions from the user, I do not believe that you'll be able to differentiate between users that have "liked" your URL.

Answer (score 0):

Use a javascript onclick to detect when the like button is clicked and localStorage to store the info?